# R 4.0.0 and stringsAsFactors

Tags: r

I am maintaining an R-based application that uses read.table(), various data.frame(), and lm()/glm()-type functions. As of version 4.0.0, R treats strings in data frames as strings rather than factors, by default. I am considering how to deal with this in order to avoid having problems show up.

I google searched for information about functions that might be affected by the change but did not find definitive lists, or utilities that might scan the package for potential problems. Have I missed anything that might help?

On the other hand, I found the essay

*Kurt Hornik: stringsAsFactors*

https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/index.html

which says, amongst other things,

> Hence, in the R Core meetings in Toulouse in 2019, it was decided to move towards using stringsAsFactors = FALSE by default, ideally starting with the 4.0.0 release.
>
> Eventually, the stringsAsFactors option will thus disappear. For the time being, it was actually made possible to consistently set the option (and hence the stringsAsFactors default) via an internal environment variable _R_OPTIONS_STRINGS_AS_FACTORS_: the base and recommended packages were already modified last year to work correctly irrespective of the default setting, and some of the regular CRAN checks will soon switch to using _R_OPTIONS_STRINGS_AS_FACTORS_=false.

If I understand this correctly, stringsAsFactors will no longer be a parameter in data.frame() and read.table() sometime in the future. And it sounds like we can now pass data frames with categorical variables represented by strings to lm(), glm(), etc and such functions will deal correctly with them automatically. So I can remove all stringsAsFactors parameters from function calls and all those functions will work correctly? Is this right? (It seems too easy.)

I am grateful for advice.
Thank you.

Comment: `stringsAsFactors` is still a parameter in data.frame but the default value (`default.stringsAsFactors()`) is now `FALSE` as opposed to `TRUE` previously. So `data.frame(a = letters[1:5])` would have `a` as characters in R 4.0.0. If you want them as factors you need to explicitly mention it `data.frame(a = letters[1:5], stringsAsFactors = TRUE)`

Comment: *"And it sounds like we can now pass data frames with categorical variables represented by strings to `lm()`, `glm()`, etc and such functions will deal correctly with them automatically"*. This is function dependent. `lm` and `glm` have automatically converted strings to factors for at least 10 years, so no changes there. (Same goes for any modeling function that relies on `model.matrix` under the hood.)

Comment: I would venture to say that *most* standard functions that need factors (by "standard" I mean `base` functions or functions in popular, well-supported packages) either (a) automatically convert strings to factors or (b) throw an error if you give them a string. In case (a), everything should work the same. In case (b), you should get an error message and be able to add a `factor()` conversion to fix it.